# Jquery `.find()` cannot find `document` `input` with value=

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button where i append inputs to the HTML DOM.
Later on i have a button to fetch input values if they matches with a keyword.
In this example "a".

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-info" id="btnAddInput">Add input</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="fetchValue">Fetch value</button>
<div id="inputs"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#btnAddInput').on('click', function() {
  $('#inputs').append('<input type="text" class="myInput"><br>');
  });
$('#fetchValue').on('click', function() {
  var value = $(document).find('input[value="a"]');
  console.log(value);
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljrkdm53/

I´ve learned that, if you add HTML to the DOM with Jquery, you sometimes have to use `document` as selector, to find elements.
But i have no success in this case.

Inputs that you add is, in my code saved into mysql.
And if you load up all saved inputs at start, the js code find values.

So, what am i missing?

Comment: You want this? https://jsfiddle.net/Ljrkdm53/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're confusing the various `value`s associated with inputs. You're not the only one!

- The `value` **attribute** specifies the *initial value* of the input. It does not change when the input's value changes, and so since you're appending an input that has no `value` attribute, then typing in it, it doesn't suddenly get a value attribute — so you can't search for it by that value.
- The `value` **property** on `HTMLInputElement` instances reflects the input's current value.
- There's also the `defaultValue` property, which reflects the `value` attribute.

If you need to find an input based on its *current* value, there's no CSS selector that will do it, you need to use a broader search and `filter`:

```
var inputsWithA = $("input").filter(function() {
    return this.value == "a";
});
```

Here's a quick example showing the values of an input's `value` property, `defaultValue` property, and `value` attribute:

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var input = $("input");
  msg("The input's <code>value</code> property is: '" + input.val() + "'");
  msg("The input's <code>defaultValue</code> property is: '" + input.prop("defaultValue") + "'");
  msg("The input's <code>value</code> <strong>attribute</strong> is: '" + input.attr("value") + "'");
  
  msg("We can only use CSS with the attribute, so for instance <code>$('input[value=\"original\"]')</code> will find it but <code>$('input[value=\"" + input.val() + "\"]')</code> will not:");
  msg("<code>$('input[value=\"original\"]')</code> found it? " +
      ($('input[value="original"]').length ? "Yes" : "No")
  );
  msg("<code>$('input[value=\"" + input.val() + "\"]')</code> found it? " +
      ($('input[value="' + input.val() + '"]').length ? "Yes" : "No")
  );
});
function msg(html) {
  $("<p>").html(html).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

```html
<p>Type something in the input, then click the button:</p>
<input type="text" value="original">
<button type="button">Click Me</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If I run that and change the input's value to "updated" before clicking the button, I get:

> The input's `value` property is: 'updated'
>
> The input's `defaultValue` property is: 'original'
>
> The input's `value` **attribute** is: 'original'
>
> We can only use CSS with the attribute, so for instance `$('input[value="original"]')` will find it but `$('input[value="updated"]')` will not:
>
> `$('input[value="original"]')` found it? Yes
>
> `$('input[value="updated"]')` found it? No

Comment: Great explaining! Thank you. I know understand. Thats why it works with preloaded values.

Comment: Even though it had `value` attribute, it would not work with `input[value="a"]` selector I suppose..

Comment: @RayonDabre: `input[value="a]` will indeed work if the markup for the element is `<input value="a">`, because as far as CSS is concerned, `value` is an attribute just like any other attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code you need.

```
$('#btnAddInput').on('click', function() {
$('#inputs').append('<input type="text" class="myInput"><br>');
});

$('#fetchValue').on('click', function() {
  var value = $('.myInput').val();
  console.log(value);
});
```

You can check it working here:

[jsfiddle.net/Ljrkdm53/7](http://check%20it:%20jsfiddle.net/Ljrkdm53/7)

Comment: but I tried it on the fiddle link you gave, and its working fine there. check it: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljrkdm53/7/

Comment: ok. i´m sorry. Edit your question a bit, then i can remove the down vote. (Cannot remove it if there is no edit)

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is that the find returns an array of objects and not one value and that the value selector only uses the initial value. You need to use an `each` function on the value you have now to do something with it.

```
$(document).find('input').each(function () {
    if( $(this).val() == "a")
        console.log( $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: In my example, im only looking for the object. But prior to T.Js answear. Your code wont work either!?

Comment: Your right. Updated the answer and also learned something in the process :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with each function.

```
$('input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'a') {
        console.log('a');
    }
});
```

Comment: @Mjukis this does work.. val() is checking the actual value. Try yourself.

Comment: oh, Yes it does. Thank you.